# C: enum VS #define for mathematical constants?

Tags: c, math, constants

I'm wondering what would be the best way to store math constants that are used throughout an entire program?

```
#define PI 3.14159265
#define SPEEDOFLIGHT 2.99792458e8
```

or

```
enum constants { PI = 3.14159265; SPEEDOFLIGHT = 2.99792458e8; }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not use `const` variables for this! In the C language, a `const` qualified variable is **not** a constant in the sense of constant expression, so it cannot be used in initializing a static/global variable. This has major practical consequences; for instance, the following will not work:

```
static const double powers_of_pi[] = { 1, PI, PI*PI, PI*PI*PI, PI*PI*PI*PI, };
```

The proper solution is `#define`. It's probably best to use the `l` suffix so that they'll have type `long double`, and include sufficiently many decimal places that the values will be correct for `long double` types up to 128-bit. Then you can use them wherever any floating point type is expected; C will silently convert them down to lower precision as needed.

Comment: +1: C const are rubbish. For example you can't even do this: 
`static const double pi=3.1415926; static const double tau=2*pi;` because in C const initializers always have to be compile time constants, which pi isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the support injecting some sanity into this topic. It seems like everyone else is coming from a C++ background and thinks what works in C++ should work in C... :-(

Comment: @Luther, shouldn't call them rubbish. They have their limited use, but certainly not the one somebody that is coming from a C++ background expects. `const` should never have been chosen as the keyword for what it stands, `unmutable` or something like that would have been much saner, for both, C and C++.

Comment: Static/global `const` arrays have some usefulness because they serve as a sort of function from the (small) integers to arbitrary data, but I can hardly think of any use for individual `const` variables... The only two that come to mind right off are using their addresses as sentinel pointer values, and exporting constants from a library without their values getting hard-coded into the calling application (which could have shared-library ABI issues).

Answer (score 10):

None of them, use constant values to preserve compiler's type checking:

```
static const double PI = 3.14159265;
static const double SPEEDOFLIGHT = 2.99792458e8;
```

- The `#define` is text replacement only and type unaware.
- Enums are not suited for all types. I am not sure but I think not even for `double` values.

EDIT: thanks `aaa`. I forgot the `static` keyword, specially useful when the constants are declared in c headers. (In C++ the static is not needed)

Comment: This is very bad advice. For instance, you won't be able to use expressions involving `PI` as initializers for static data.

Comment: Agree with R. **You can't even initalize another const with a const in C.**

Comment: This here is really an answer in terms of C++. Since the question is tagged C, it is not appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Personally i prefer to just make pi and c = 1 and let the universe deal with the problem

Answer (score 3):

Since enum's are *integer* constants, I would go with `#define`.

I agree with jdehaan that global `const` objects are even better.

Comment: Kudos for being the only answer to explicitly mention that `enum` is only for integer types, but I disagree that global `const` objects are better (at least not without mentioning their limitations).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with jdehaan, prefer constants to do more explicit type checking/conversion.

In addition, using an enum like you described isn't really the purpose of an enum.  Those constants are only mathematically related (if cosmologist hocus-pocus ends up being correct).  The purpose of an enum is to combine like values, such as:

```
enum color
{
  red = 0xFF0000;
  yellow = 0xFFFF00;
  baby_puke_green = 0x9ACD32;
}
```